Signing PDF from Pkcs11Interop and DevExpress C# .net
I'm attempting to sign PDF documents using the pkcs11interop library in conjunction with DevExpress's PDF libraries.
I have successfully implemented PDF signing using DevExpress's PDF libraries, and I am now attempting to integrate the pkcs11interop library to sign the PDF documents with a key stored in a Hardware Security Module (HSM). However, despite being able to sign the digest and verify the signature using pkcs11interop, the resulting PDF signature is invalid when applied to the document.
PDF Signature Screenshot:

Below is a simplified version of the code I have implemented:
using (var signer = new PdfDocumentSigner(File.OpenRead("Document.pdf")))
{
    // Specify the information about the signature metadata:
    var digestCalculator = new DigestCalculator(DevExpress.Office.DigitalSignatures.HashAlgorithmType.SHA256);

    var signerInfo = new ExternalSignerInfo(PdfSignatureType.PAdES, 8000, digestCalculator);

    // Create a new form field:
    var fieldInfo = new PdfSignatureFieldInfo(1) { SignatureBounds = new PdfRectangle(10, 10, 100, 100) };

    // Apply the metadata to the form field:
    var builder = new PdfDeferredSignatureBuilder(signerInfo, fieldInfo);

    // Add the signature to the document:
    var deferredSigner = signer.SignDeferred(builder);

    // Obtain the document hash and hash algorithm's object identifier:
    var digest = deferredSigner.HashValue;
    var digestAlgorithmOID = digestCalculator.AlgorithmOid;


    // Generate the signature content to insert into the document:
    byte[] signature = SignData(digest);
    if (signature == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Signature is null");

        return;
    }

    VerifySignature(digest, signature);

    // Add the signature contents and save the document to the file:
    deferredSigner.Sign("signedDemo.pdf", signature);
}

Below are the function to sign with Pkcs11Interop:
public static byte[] SignData(byte[] dataToSign)
{

    try
    {
        // Open RW session
        using (ISession session = GetHSMSession(SessionType.ReadWrite))
        {
            session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, userPin);

            var searchTemplate = new List<IObjectAttribute>
        {
            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY),
            session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_LABEL, certificateLabel)
        };

            var foundObjects = session.FindAllObjects(searchTemplate);

            if (foundObjects.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Certificate not found in HSM.");
            }

            var certificateObject = foundObjects.First();

            // Specify signing mechanism
            IMechanism mechanism = session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS);

            // Sign data
            byte[] signature = session.Sign(mechanism, certificateObject, dataToSign);

            session.Logout();

            return signature;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while Sign Data With Certificate: {ex.ToString()}");
    }
    return null;
}

